# Fastest persistent key/value db for fixed size keys and only insert/fetch (no delete/update)?

Tags: database, leveldb, acid, rocksdb, nosql

Given the following requirements of a persistent key/value store:

- Only fetch, insert, and full iteration of all values (for exports) are required
- No deleting values or updating values
- Keys are always the same size
- Code embedded in the host application

And given this usage pattern:

- Fetches are random
- Inserts and fetches are interleaved with no predictability
- Keys are random, and inserted in random order

What is the best on-disk data structure/algorithm given the requirements?

Can a custom implementation exceed the performance of LSM-based (Log Structured Merge) implementations (i.e. leveldb, rocksdb)?

Would a high performance custom implementation for these requirements also be considerably simpler in implementation?

Comment: Are the keys going to be inserted in sorted order?  Are the fetches going to be specific keys, or ranges, or wildcards?

Comment: @ChrisShain Question has been updated to provide a usage pattern

Comment: If you keep inserting keys but never deleting keys, you will end up with running out of space eventually.  So in your workload do you stop writing at some point?

Comment: @keelar Writing never stops, and keys are never deleted from the database. If the server operator wants to keep only a certain amount of history, there is a manual process where the server is taken down and a separate job runs that copies all the data from the existing database into a new database, minus entries that belong to ledgers that are too old. That's why "iterate all values" is needed (for this export).

Answer (score 5):

While it might be possible to have better performance custom implementation for your requirements, a well-configured RocksDB should be able to beat most of such custom implementations in your case.  Here is what I would config RocksDB:

First, since you don't have updates and deletes, it's best to **compact all data into big files in RocksDB**.  Because RocksDB sort these keys in a customizable order, having some big files gives you faster read performance as binary search across some big files is faster than across multiple small files.  Typically, having big files hurt the performance of compaction --- the process of reorganizing big part of the data in RocksDB such that 1. multiple updates associated with a single key will be merged; 2. execute deletions to free disk space; 3. keep the data sorted.  However, since you don't have updates and deletes, having big files give you fast read and write performance.

Second, **specify large bits for bloom filter**, this allow you to avoid most IOs when you're likely to issue some queries where keys do not exist in RocksDB.

So a read request goes like this.  First, it compares the query key with the key ranges of those big files to identify which file the query key might located.  Then, once the file(s) which key-range covers the query key, it will computes the bloom bits of the query key to see if the query key may exist in those files.  If so, then a binary search inside each file will be triggered to identify the matched data.

As for scan operation, since RocksDB internally sort data in a user customizable order, scan can be done very efficiently using RocksDB's iterator.

More information about RocksDB basics can be found in [here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Basics).

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know - can a custom implementation beat RocksDB? It sounds like you're saying no. I don't want to waste my time trying to write something specialized if there is low chance of out-performing RocksDB.

Comment: We never do a bulk-load though.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: I have updated the answer.  Basically configuring RocksDB to have big files still apply as you don't have updates and deletes.  This gives you faster read and write without much penalty.